# Magento 1.9 : How to get Image label under the main image?

Tags: magento-1.9, image, product-images, media-images

How can I get image "label" to print/output under the main image??

[image]

Need to display the Image label change according to the selection of the thumbnail image.

(e.g Front, Rear, Side etc)

Answer (score 1):

For main image : in media.phtml template file:

```php
<span><?= $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ?></span>
```

also see https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/blob/1.9.4.x/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code-

```
<?php echo (Mage::app()->getLayout()->checkVersion('1.7.x.x') ? $this->htmlEscape : $this->escapeHtml).($_image->getImage()->getLabel()) ?>
```

This one getting image label and you can save that into any data attribute and show that title or text with jquery.

Comment: Why are you using checkVersion ?